# Ant script to Automate sub ant scripts

Tags: ant, atg

I have a big ATG project base that is divided into smaller modules. Now the entire project has an Ant build target and an EAR build target. These smaller modules also have a separate build target. Now I what I want to do is make an Ant script to build these smaller modules in combinations, these combinations can be anything as e.g:

- x2x-project---->has a ANT target which will build all a,b,c and a EAR ANT script that will build the EAR all of all module
- a-module
- b-module
- c-module

So now if I want (A+EAR a), (a + b + EAR a + EAR b)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at:
http://atgant.sourceforge.net/

I wrote this quite a while back, but it should work as ATG's module system is pretty stable. It only targets the recursive finding of modules, and not any details of the compilation (though an example is included). It has been used on at least one large build.

I no longer maintain this (moved onto something else), but source code is available in http://sourceforge.net/projects/atgant/. YMMV